# Create Unique Sub List within List in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint

Im trying to create a Unique sub list within a list in Sharepoint Online (2013).

I realize that sub lists arent exactly possible and you can use lookup fields to attach another list. This doesn't seem like it will work for my situation.

I am trying to have a list item that allows you to upload unique files per list item. For Example:

```
Reports May 2015
---School.xml
---Food.xml
Reports Jun 2016
---University.xml
---Beach.xml
```

Each list item will have a set of unique files related to it.The user needs to be able to make the List item themselves (Reports ... in this case), this will of course have other fields and descriptions attached to it (hence the list) and then be able to upload unique documents to that list item.

Im having problems figuring out how to do this in SharePoint. If there is another way to go about this better i am up for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right - sublists aren't a thing in SharePoint. Reading your requirements, I'm not sure if you need two lists to get what your looking for. Would it be possible to have a single Document Library with a custom field for "Category" or "Report Month". This field could either be a Single line of text field or Choice field. From there you could create a custom view to group by this field and give the hierarchical view from your example.

If you need separate metadata for the grouping/top level, you may need to use Lookups. If I was putting together the solution, I would set up a List and a corresponding Library with a Lookup field to the List. Each of the documents uploaded to the Library would reference the List via that Lookup. To provide an interface for interacting with both within the same view, you'd need to frontend it with some custom code such as a SharePoint-Hosted App.